# Reload Same Page ionic2

Tags: ionic2

Hello how can i reload the same component in ionic2 app.I have the following pages pushed to stack like this

```
Estimate List --> Main Estimate  --> History  --> Main Estimate
```

Here user can select an estimate from the estimate list.From there he can view the history all estimates given for a particular customer.From the estimate list if clicks on an estimate i should load Main Estimate Component.

If i simply push the Main Estimate Component the previous estimate remains in stack.What i need is remove the previous Estimate and History pages from stack and keep only the new estimate something like this

```
Estimate List --> Main Estimate
```

Can somebody please suggest me a way to achieve this.Thank you

Comment: Try this `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);`

Comment: `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);` makes my MainEstimate component load again but it destroys the Estimate List Component.When i click on back button i want the estimate list to be present